# How to count the decimal places of an double variable in c++?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, decimal

for a course at my university i need to write a program which converts a number into
natural language e.g. if the user enters "2.55" the program outputs "two point five five".
And i'm close to finish it the only thing i cant get are numbers after the point.
I'm not allowed to use strings. Here is how i tried to get the count of decimal places:

```
i=0;
while((wert - (long int)wert) != 0){
    wert /= 10;
    i++;
}
```

But it gives me the value of 356 decimal places for the example number "2.55". Is there any method wihout using strings to count the decimal places?

Best Regards

Comment: Floating point doesn't work that way... it's hard to predict how a number like "2.55" will be stored as a double - you might get something like "2.549999...". Choose a fixed precision and stick to it.

Comment: Instead of comparing exactly with zero, try checking whether the difference between zero and the number is very small.

Comment: What number range is the expected input?  Is it the complete floating point range for a 64-bit system? Is it allowed to parse the input into two independent integers?  Depending on the answers, you may be able to parse the input differently.

Comment: In his his word the program should be able to show you any real number which is in the range of double should represendable e.g. "2.1" should give "two point one" and "2.10" should give "tow point one zero".

Comment: Note that "2.1" and "2.10" are string representations of the same double. I would try to clarify what is meant by "not allowed to use strings".

Comment: I asked him and he said that we are note allowed to use strings and any other form of array.

Comment: In what format are you receiving your input? I assume you are receiving strings and then converting these to doubles? In order to parse "2.1" and "2.10" correctly you're going to have to use the original string or some other information (like max number of sig-figs)...otherwise it is impossible as I understand it.

Comment: Do you have complete freedom in how you input your number as long as you only use non-array `double`s and `int`s in your program?

Comment: I have to save my input directly to an double variable and im allowed to use integer casts if i need to remove the digits after the decimal point which i used to write the function which counts the digits before decimal point. @uesp: no i dont get the value as a string i have to use "cin >> value" and have to save it directly into the variable.

Comment: @Cracksoldier I'm still confused whether you want to know the number of decimal places or the decimal places. What would be the answer for `2.55`? 2 or "55"?

Comment: @Axel the answer to "2.55" would be "55"

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to use a `double` to do this due to floating point precision. For example, a `double` set to 0.2 will have many more decimal places than 1 since 0.2 cannot be represented precisely. (Why not examine the actual value of the `double` in your debugger?) 2.55 cannot be represented precisely either.

Probably the simplest thing for you to do here is use a string to represent your number and base your parser on that.

Comment: Thats my problem i had already finished the program using strings but my professor insists on using only double type.

Comment: That makes the problem artificially difficult. Are you sure the professor is *insisting* on that?

Comment: Yes he is insisting on using only double and integer datatypes but according to him i would only need double.

Comment: @Cracksoldier To summarize, the assignment artificially constrains not using any character or string parsing techniques.

Answer (score 2):

If the user is entering the number, it will be coming in as a string, or shall we say into a byte array, so there is no need to bring floating-point into it at all. Just locate the decimal place in the data and then start counting digits.

NB The question in your title is meaningless. Floating-point variables don't have decimal places, they have binary places, and decimal and binary places are incommensurable. If your professor wants you to use floating-point he needs [re-education](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) himself.

Comment: As I understand it, the requirement is to process a `double`. And of course you can talk about decimal places - that's the places in the decimal representation of the double. IIRC, implementations (used to) exist where floats are not stored in IEEE/binary form.

Comment: @Axel Exactly, you can talk about decimal places in the result of converting the double to decimal. Not in the double itself. It's meaningless. They aren't in there.

Comment: Since every double represents a unique number that *has* decimal places I think it's clear what is meant. And again, there are systems (mainframes being an example) where floating point values in C do *not* have binary places according to your definition. As for the task itself: I think it's ok as an assignment, since this can really be an eye-opener, and I'm pretty sure the prof knows the article you linked. At least I hope so.

Answer (score 1):

The IEEE 64-bit binary number closest to 2.55 is 2.54999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875, which only has 50 digits after the decimal point.

The repeated division makes no sense. Ignoring rounding error, the values of `wert` would be 2.55, 0.255, 0.0255, 0.00255, etc. none of which is equal to any long. The loop terminates when `wert` underflows to zero.

Instead, you should be multiplying by 10. However, if you keep the leading digits you may get a number too large to store as a long before getting equality. Instead, I suggest subtracting off the integer part at each step, and stopping when the result is zero.

That will still lead to a 50 decimal place answer, but if your professor insists on double, maybe that is what is wanted.

Comment: This is a good answer. It gets at the fundamental absurdity or vagueness of the question.

2.55 can be reasonably printed with anywhere from three to 50 digits.

Looking at this from the perspective of a float, every 32-bit float can be uniquely identified by a sign, exponent, and a nine-decimal-digit mantissa. However in most cases that does not give you the precise value of that float -- just a nearby one. In the worst case a float can take 112 digits to print precisely, and a double is much worse.

http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/float-precisionfrom-zero-to-100-digits-2/

Answer (score 1):

```
char* fractpart(double f)
{
char chrstr[5];
char charary={'1','2','3',....,'0'};
int intary={1,2,3,...,0};
int count=0,x,y;
f=f-(int)f;
        while(f<=1)
        {
         f=f*10;
           for(y=0;y<10;y++)
           {
               if((int)f==intary[y])
               { 
               chrstr[count]=charary[y];
               break;
               }
           }
   f=f-(int)f;
      if(f<=0.01 || count==4)
      break;
      if(f<0)
      f=-f;
      count++;
}
     return(chrstr);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer will be more useful if you include an explanation of how your code works and how it answers the problem described in the question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the maximal number of digits you have to support after the point.Let's say `n` digits maximum. Multiply the fractional part of your number by `10^n` and then shift the resulting number right until the last digit is different from `0` to remove trailing zeroes. Then print the digits one by one:

```
void printDigitsAfterPoint(double x) {
    int k = Math.round((x-(int) x)*Math.pow10(n));
    // remove trailing zeroes
    while (k!=0 && k%10==0) {
        k/=10;
    }
    // output digits
    while (k!=0) {
        output(k%10); // you already should have a method like this...
        k/=10;
    }
}
```

Make sure to add code for handling negative values of `x`. I'm sure your prof will try that...

EDIT: Forgot to change the declaration. Fixed.

Comment: i have added code to handle negative values its on the top of my program directly after the "cin"

Comment: Ehm, one more question: You need the digits, not the number of digits, right? I misunderstood your question. Will update again.

Comment: This will most likely work very unreliably, because: `10.0 times 0.1 is hardly ever 1.0
~Brian Kernighan`

Comment: No, `10 times 0.1` is always `1.0`. The problem is, there is no `0.1`... ;-)

Comment: You can do whatever you want with them. It's `k%10` in the second loop.

Comment: Yes the problem is for example if you type in "10.00" the program should output "one zero dot zero zero"

Comment: Now that is impossible using `doubles` (unless you always output 2 digits after the point). `10` and `10.0` and `10.00` are all the same `double`.

Comment: Thats the fact that drives me crazy because he insists that it is possible i'll ask him tomorrow to show me his solution

Comment: @Kupto: I added rounding. Now it should be reliable as long as he doesn't enter more than n digits after the point.

Comment: If the number of digits after the point are not defined (or not allowed to be calculated), then this professor is lacking numerical analysis knowledge.  A good test case is to have a zero somewhere after the point, but between non-zero digits.  For example, what does the algorithm do if the input number is `1234.678901234` (this example has `n == 9`).  As an experiment, I have tried a different approach that does not use the `pow` function in `<cmath>`.  My algorithm will fail if the number of digits after the point are not known or prevented from being calculated by professor constraints.